# can not compile my code with template and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, make-shared

I have some code :

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class A 
{
    private:
        std::string field1;
        std::string field2;
        
    public :
        A(std::string const& s1):field1(s1){};
        virtual ~A(){};
};


template<class CLIENT>
class B 
{
    private:
        A field1;
        A field2;
        CLIENT field3;
        
    public :
        B(A const&  a1):field1(a1){};
        virtual ~B(){};
        CLIENT muFunc(){return field3;};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string s("s");
    A a(s);
    std::make_shared<B<A>>(a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

when I tried to compile it, I get the following error :

main2.cc: Dans l'instanciation de « B::B(const A&) [with CLIENT = A] » :
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4:   requis par « void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = B; _Args = {A&}; _Tp = B] »
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:455:4:   requis par « static void std::allocator_traitsstd::allocator<_Tp1 >::construct(std::allocator_traitsstd::allocator<_Tp1 >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = B; _Args = {A&}; _Tp = B; std::allocator_traitsstd::allocator<_Tp1 >::allocator_type = std::allocator<B >] »
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:520:39:   requis par « std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<_Tp, _Alloc, _Lp>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace(_Alloc, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {A&}; _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B >; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u] »
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:615:4:   requis par « std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, _Tp*, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B >; _Args = {A&}; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u] »
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1100:35:   requis par « std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<B >; _Args = {A&}; _Tp = B; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u] »
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:319:64:   requis par « std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<B >; _Args = {A&}; _Tp = B] »
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:619:14:   requis par « std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::allocate_shared(const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B >; _Args = {A&}] »
/opt/gcc_6_3/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:635:39:   requis par « std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = B; _Args = {A&}] »
main2.cc:37:26:   requis depuis ici
main2.cc:28:28: erreur : no matching function for call to « A::A() »
B(A const&  a1):field1(a1){};
^
main2.cc:14:3: note : candidate: A::A(const string&)
A(std::string const& s1):field1(s1){};
^
main2.cc:14:3: note :   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main2.cc:7:7: note : candidate: A::A(const A&)
class A
^
main2.cc:7:7: note :   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main2.cc:28:28: erreur : no matching function for call to « A::A() »
B(A const&  a1):field1(a1){};
^
main2.cc:14:3: note : candidate: A::A(const string&)
A(std::string const& s1):field1(s1){};
^
main2.cc:14:3: note :   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main2.cc:7:7: note : candidate: A::A(const A&)
class A
^
main2.cc:7:7: note :   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

I don't understand the error as the variable a is already created. Why does the compiler need a constructor without any paramter and how do I fix this issue.

thanks.

Comment: Ask yourself, how is `CLIENT field3` getting initialized?

Comment: Aside: You don't need the semicolon after a function definition's body. The extra semicolon inside a class definition is legal, but gets parsed as an "empty-declaration" separately from the member function.

Comment: I didn't want the field3 to be initialized. In my idea, it is not the constructor that initalize it but some other method. And therefore the pb did not come from field3.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I just put in the class A a default constructor without any parameter and it works....